# What was the reason that the USA never accepted PRC as an ally after Chinese economic boom?

Tags: united-states, china

What was the reason that the USA never accepted PRC as an ally after [Chinese economic miracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_economic_reform) ... as same as they accepted [India as their ally](http://nation.foxnews.com/2017/06/26/trump-alliance-india-has-never-looked-brighter-modi-vows-increased-anti-terror-effort)?

1. [Major Takeaways From Indian PM Narendra Modi's First Summit With Donald Trump](http://thediplomat.com/2017/06/6-major-takeaways-from-indian-pm-narendra-modi-first-summit-with-donald-trump/)

Answer (score 3):

Asking why the US never accepted ally status, implies that China offered it. I don't believe that has been the case.

China and the US cooperate when it is in the interests of both nations. Both are large enough that neither needs the other, the economies are so intertwined that a war between the two counties would have serious economic consequences, but unlike the US and UK, there is no long standing shared cultural heritage.

Opinion: I tend to characterize the relationship between the two countries more as respect, than friendship. The interests of the two nations diverge enough at times that ally status is probably not something that will ever happen.

Answer (score -4):

The blame is 100% on the Chinese side.

1. Immediately after WWII, the US tried to make peace between CCP and KMT. This effort was genuine but was nevertheless feeble because the volatile situation was beyond the ability of then American leadership.
2. When China's civil war broke out, American attitude was something like this: if war is how you settle dispute, we will let you fight it out; after that we will resume business with whoever wins.
3. As soon as China's civil war began to settle, the US made a gesture of détente by staying [John Leighton Stuard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Leighton_Stuart) in Nanjing, hoping to open up communication with the CCP.
4. But Mao had decided to side with the Soviet. In order to clear Stalin's suspicion, Mao gave the US a cold shoulder and wrote an open letter to ridicule Stuart’s departure.

   4.1 Why Mao favoured the Soviet is still open to speculation. Of all the colonial powers, the Russians in Manchuria were famous for lacking the sense of superiority, not only because the Russians lived side by side with the Chinese but also because because Russians were frequent targets of Chinese scams - as was witness by a famous writer [Zhu Ziqing](https://sanwen8.cn/p/Y8e2bN.html) - and fooling Russians had become a staple of Chinese jokes. Back at that time, Mao as well as the entire Chinese population were suffering from inferiority complex.
5. Stalin was still suspecting China of buttering its bread on both sides. Mao sent troops to Korea in order to draw American blood and, in political jargon, made his bones.
6. Between 1978 and 1991, China and the US were de facto allies against the Soviet.
7. After 1991, China became number 2. From a gaming point of view, no body likes number 2: number 1 is directly threatened by number 2, and the rest of the world would side whoever becomes number 1. Number 2 has to tough it out: either overthrow number 1, or wait until number 1 implodes, or become number 1 himself.

Comment: This answer tells us that you don't know when "Chinese Economic Boom" took place.

Comment: China's economic miracle was pretty much America's making. America tends to push its allies to the front, which is not what China wants.

Comment: Kindly, review the question again.

Comment: OK. I revised accordingly.

Comment: China became #2 as in "secondary," or #2 as in what little kids are told to say in stead of "poop"?

Comment: (7) needs to be elaborated along with references. (1) to (5) need to be deleted.

Comment: Historical legacy still plays a major role. When Nixon visited China, one of the mutual understanding is, although we will begin bilateral cooperation, our media outlets' attitudes will remain unchanged, so don't take it too seriously if you hear something unpleasant on TV.

Comment: The US indeed tried very hard to kiss Mao's smelly butt, but each attempt was spurned with redoubled vehemence because Mao did not want Stalin to think he had any secret dealings with the US. After Stalin's death, Mao considered himself the rightful heir of communist #1 and tried to teach Khrushchev his place, the consequence of which was Sino-Soviet split.

Comment: After Sino-Soviet split, American overture no longer looked repugnant. Nevertheless, Kissinger begged his Chinese counterpart to not present this diplomatic breakthrough as an American defeat. https://books.google.com/books?id=xJ3YR-Y5ANwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=nixon+and+mao&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj477jQwunUAhXJTSYKHaTaDuwQ6AEIIjAA#v=snippet&q=%22As%20a%20major%20American%20defeat%22&f=false

Comment: Khrushchev could have been China's Deng if Nixon was elected in 1961, and all these stragegic butt kissing could have happened between the Soviet and the US. Unfortunately, in 1960 election, America made the wrong choice.

Comment: why is this answer dimmed?